# Excel - Conditional Format Top Value IF Both Cells Are Not Blank

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that shows the daily sales on one row and if that month is the current month will show the last years sales on the row below that - else it will be `""`.

I then want to format the values to highlight the top 1 value, but only if both cells are not blank (or `""`).

Example (snippets):

```
   A               B            C            D
   ====================================================
 1 = Jan         |   1-Jan-18 |   2-Jan-18 |   3-Jan-18
 2 = 2018        |        Mon |        Tue |        Wed
 3 = MI          |          0 |          4 |          4
 4 = SC          |          0 |          0 |          0
 5 = Subtotal    |          0 |          4 |          4
 6 = DS          |          0 |          0 |          0
 7 = Total       |          0 |          4 |          4
 8 = Daily Sales |         $- |  $1,763.72 |  $1,763.72 
 9 = ""          |         "" |         "" |         ""
. . .
51 = Jun         |   1-Jun-17 |   2-Jun-17 |   3-Jun-17
52 = 2017        |        Thu |        Fri |        Sat
53 = MI          |         29 |         33 |         33
54 = SC          |         40 |         34 |         38
55 = Subtotal    |         69 |         67 |         71
56 = DS          |         37 |         35 |         39
57 = Total       |        106 |        102 |        110
58 = Daily Sales | $46,738.63 | $44,974.91 | $48,502.35 
59 = Last Year   | $34,899.21 | $34,557.87 | $36,945.18
```

[image: Showing above table as a picture]

Please note the `""` aren't actually there. I'm just showing the values are blank.

So cells `B8:D9` should not be highlighted, as row 9 is blank. Cells `B58:D58` should be highlighted, as both row 58 and row 59 are not blank and row 58 is the higher value.

How do I go about doing this? I was trying just a "Top 1" value, but it highlights the values in row 8 which just looks weird as there is no values in row 9 to compare with.

Solution should be fully automatic. I don't want to manually have to update conditional formats, cells, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using `=AND(B9<>"",B8>B9)` for cells `=$B$8:$B$9` (example range) and just copied that for other cells (eg. `=AND(C9<>"",C8>C9)` for cells `=$C$8:$C$9`.

Answer (score 0):

Select cell **B8** and create a new conditional formatting rule using a formula. Put in this formula:

```
=AND(COUNT(B8:B9)=2,B8=MAX(B8:B9))
```

Select cell **B9** and create a new conditional formatting rule with this formula:

```
=AND(COUNT(B8:B9)=2,B9=MAX(B8:B9))
```

Set the desired formats for both rules. Apply the rules to more cells or just copy the two cells and use Paste Special > Formats to apply to any other pair of cells that are one below the other.
[image]